# SQLiteException syntax error (code 1) when trying to get count of table

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to get the count of images from an Android device. Here is the code I use to do it:

```
    int count = -1;

    Cursor cursor = resolver.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] {"count(*) AS count"},
            null,
            null,
            null);

    if(cursor != null){
        if(cursor.moveToNext()){
            count = cursor.getInt(0);
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
```

This works most the of time, and has never failed in my testing of it. However, Crashlytics is occasionally reporting the following exception:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException Unable to create
>   application com.forever.forever.Utils.app.ProdForeverApplication:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ")": syntax error (code
>   1): , while compiling: SELECT count(*) AS count FROM images WHERE (
>   mime_type NOT
>   IN('application/vnd.oma.drm.message','application/vnd.oma.drm.content','application/vnd.oma.drm.dcf')
>   AND ())

Does anyone know what is going on here??

Answer (score 1):

There is an empty `AND ()` in the SQL text (as you can see in the exception message). Obviously a condition is missing here. Try to provide a dummy condition yielding always TRUE:

```
"0=0"
```

Probably you have to provide it for the last parameter (I don't know which one is which, so) or as part of the string array

```
Cursor cursor = resolver.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        new String[] {"count(*) AS count"},
        null,
        null,
        "0=0");
```

Or

```
Cursor cursor = resolver.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        new String[] {"count(*) AS count", "0=0"},
        null,
        null,
        null);
```

The resulting SQL must be:

```
SELECT count(*) AS count FROM images
WHERE ( mime_type NOT IN('application/vnd.oma.drm.message',
   'application/vnd.oma.drm.content','application/vnd.oma.drm.dcf') AND (0=0))
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out. Do you know of any reason why it would work most of the time when providing null and only occasionally crash with that exception?

Comment: It depends whether always the same SQL template is resolved. Are there two versions around? One with the `AND (...)` and one without? Id `MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` always the same?